# Shared reputation between meta-stackoverflow and stackoverflow

Tags: feature-request

Look at [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2001/migrate-reputation-from-other-stackoverflow-sites-to-meta) question instead

Just a suggestion. I think it would make sense if there was some kind of shared reputation between meta-stackoverflow and stack overflow. I'm not saying they should be the same, just suggesting some proportion of your stack overflow reputation should be carried over to meta.

Note: This really makes a difference to me, since I'm still a newbie on stack overflow

Comment: You may want to delete this question, before other users downvote it for being a duplicate question!

Comment: @kanamekun: this is a duplicate, but when I searched, I couldn't find anything on this topic, but I can now see the top result in the related links is a dupe. Perhaps it would be best to leave it to redirect other people to the original question.

Comment: Could someone close this? I think it is still useful as a redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been suggested before and in numerous forms.

The basic retaliation is this:

Your reputation on StackOverflow signifies some sort of knowledge about programming.

Your reputation on Meta signifies some sort of knowledge about StackOverflow and the other websites, not their subject matter.

The same line of thinking can be applied to the other sites as well.

Comment: Still, I think that the more you use stack overflow, the more suitable you are to commenting on the site in general

Comment: You'd be surprised.